# Nested Loop example: Histogram python

Tags: python

I am completely new to coding and taking IT 140 and I've been struggling with the practice question. I can't seem to figure out where to start. TIA!

Run the program below and observe the output. Modify the program to print one asterisk per 5 units. So if the user enters 40, print 8 asterisks.

```py
num = 0
while num >= 0:
    num = int(input('Enter an integer (negative to quit):\n'))

    if num >= 0:
        print('Depicted graphically:')
        for i in range(num):
            print('*', end=' ')
        print('\n')

print('Goodbye.')
```

Comment: Change `for i in range(num):` to `for i in range(num//5):` to divide their number by 5 so the loop iterates 1/5 the amount of times.

Comment: Well the code you have available loops for `num` times with `for i in range(num):`. What would you need to change to loop less time?

Comment: @code_noob Programmer's answer would print one asterisk for value 2 and 2 asterisks for value 7 because it doesn't require at least 5 for an asterisk to be printed. 
My answer would print no asterisk for 2 and 1 asterisk for 7 because it does require at least 5, which did you intend? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly what you want has been built into the `range` function : it has an optional, third `step` argument, just add that to your range call:

```py
num = int(input('Enter an integer (negative to quit):\n'))
while num >= 0:
    print('Depicted graphically:')
    for i in range(0, num, 5):
        print('*', end=' ')
    print()
    num = int(input('Enter an integer (negative to quit):\n'))

print('Goodbye.')
```

Additionally, I have simplified your code a bit.

Comment: Thank you so much! After looking at what you did I see what I was doing wrong. I was doing for i in range(0,40,5): instead of the for i in range(0,num,5). Which kept giving me the same answer no matter what I was putting into the input.

Answer (score 0):

If you make a modular division in the for loop it should achieve what you want
(an asterisk for every 5)

```
num = 0
while num >= 0:
    num = int(input('Enter an integer (negative to quit):\n'))

    if num >= 0:
        print('Depicted graphically:')
        for i in range(num//5):
            print('*', end=' ')
        print('\n')

print('Goodbye.')
```

Sample out:

```
Enter an integer (negative to quit):
10
Depicted graphically:
* * 

Enter an integer (negative to quit):
5
Depicted graphically:
* 

Enter an integer (negative to quit):
12
Depicted graphically:
* * 

Enter an integer (negative to quit):
3
Depicted graphically:
```

Comment: Thank you for answering and showing me a different way of coding it.